# How to read lines in a file using Java without losing the tabs, spaces in the beginning (indent)?

Tags: java

How to read lines in a file using Java without losing the tabs, spaces in the beginning (indent)? I need this to read a sourcecode and than to print it out.

I am doing it like this:

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            aList.add(line);
        }
```

(of course with try catch blocks)

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think you're "losing the tabs, spaces in the beginning"?

Comment: Try printing out again and see what happens.

Comment: What you do looks ok - you could also use [Files.readAllLines()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) that does exactly that, without the need to deal with BufferedReaders and loops.

Comment: try aList.add(line + "\r\n") instead.  (That's for windows.  Just "\n" on linux/mac).

Comment: You should let us know how you are out putting/displaying the lines. That's most likely the problem. Also what is aList? ArrayList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `aList`, presumably a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), is dropping the tab character during rendering.

One solution is to replace your tabs with spaces:

```
aList.add(line.replaceAll("\t", "    "));
```

Yet another solution is to write your own ListCellRenderer using a JTextPane, although this is not without its [pitfalls](http://www.coderanch.com/t/488404/GUI/java/tab-not-recognised-JList).

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the reply! This helped! I was appending a buffer to show a sourcefile in a HTML page, but the HTML render was loosing the indentation, so I had to add the whitespaces like this: & nbsp.